# значения для ключа при POST запросе

Tags: post

Есть сайт на который я хочу отправить POST-запрос. Есть ключ`list-abitur` и его значение `%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F`, а обработанный(parsed) выглядит так `Подавшие заявления`. Обьясните  алгоритм преобразования, пожалуйста(Если это не индивидуальность сайта)

Answer (score 0):

Текст закодирован для URL (URL-encoding). Это стандарт, а не уникальность сайта.
В URL можно использовать только ограниченный набор символов **US-ASCII** (цифры, буквы латинского алфавита и т.п.). Символы, не входящие в этот набор кодируются особым образом (кириллица, естественно, не входит в **US-ASCII**). Почти цитата из Википедии:

> сначала каждый символ кодируется в UTF-8 в последовательность из двух
>   байтов, а затем каждый байт этой последовательности записывается в
>   шестнадцатеричном представлении с предшествующим знаком процента (%)

URL-encoding используется и в GET-запросах (в строке URL), и в POST-запросах (когда ключи и их значения передаются в теле HTTP-запроса).
P.S. Кодирование значений ключей в URL-encoding - это стандарт, но ему есть альтернатива. Можно передавать в теле запроса JSON. Понять, что используется именно URL-encoding можно по HTTP-заголовку `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` Если используется JSON, заголовок `Content-Type` будет иметь значение `application/json`.

Answer (score 0):

Это описано в RFC, список RFC можно посмотреть на [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

Comment: День добрый. Можете краткую выжимку вставить в ответ? ^_^